# How do I add a single character in a string in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, character

I am beginner in C. I want to add just single characters to a string , I have tried `strcpy()` but it only copies two string. How can I do it? Are there any functions or piece of code that can help me?
I have tried doing this `str[i] = c;` in a for loop, but can't add any character like this, I understood.
How add single character to a string in c?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("DATA.DAT", "rb");
    char c, str[15][200], temp[200];
    int i = 0, n = 0;   
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        str[n][i] = c;// Problem because need to copy in a string not assgin
        if(c == '\n')
            n++;
        i++;
    }

    int a = 0;
    for(a = 0; a <= n; a++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str[a]);
    }
    int j, k;
    
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for(k = j; k < n; k++)
        {
            if(strcmp(str[j], str[k]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], str[k]);
                strcpy(str[k], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    for(j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        printf("%s\n", str[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question by giving sample input/output?

Comment: Do you mean append it to the end so it gets longer?

Comment: `str[i] = c;` is the correct syntax for putting a single char `c` into character array (string) `str`.

Comment: Perhaps it would be time to add some *code* to your question.

Comment: *but it only copies two string* – No, it copies *source string* to *destination string*.

Answer (score 0):

Since re-assigning the entire string char-by-char as in `s(n)printf` or `strcat` in a loop could be expensive on each call, since their runtime speed is dependent on the length of the destination string as well as the source string,  my suggestion is:

Assign an array large enough to receive an `output` buffer, whose size is the size of the source string as well as the max length of however many characters could possibly be appended:

```
char *output = malloc(strlen(source) + MAX_APPENDED);
int i;

if(NULL == output)
{
    // Handle error
}

for(i = 0; i < MAX_APPENDED; i++)
{ 
    output[strlen(source) + i] = appendChars[i];
}
output[strlen(source) + i] = '\0';

free(output);
output = NULL;
```

Variables meanings hopefully can be inferred from their names.